# Data science : correlation between quantitative and qualitative variables (in python)

Tags: python, correlation, data-science

I want to know if it is possible to measure the correlation between a quantitative variable (in my case the average daily consumption of households) and a qualitative variable (in my case the month : 1, 2, ..., 12) in python ?

month | avg_daily_consumption 
------------------------------------------ 
1         | 12.11836586156116 
2         |11.713968603585668 
3         |11.902829015188159 
4         |10.12066900094302 
5         |8.879703717271864 
6         |8.384419625257689 
7         |8.146453593663365 
8         |7.961394876525876 
9         |8.748848024841289 
10       |9.820944144869841 
11       |11.247017177860053 
12       |12.069888731716086

Thanks.

Comment: I should say that when positing a problem here you should show how you tried to address this for your self, show your code and what output it produced. That is how Stackoverflow works. That said. I have produced some code below which I believe does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **numpy** and **matplotlib** libraries to show if there is any correlation.

The following was written in a Jupyter notebook but should work in Python with the removal of the line commented #remove

```
import numpy as np

#x values
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

# y values 
y = [12.11836586156116, 11.713968603585668, 11.902829015188159, 10.12066900094302, 8.879703717271864, 8.384419625257689, 8.146453593663365, 7.961394876525876, 8.748848024841289, 9.820944144869841, 11.247017177860053 , 12.069888731716086]

print( np.corrcoef(x, y))
```

This outputs:
[[ 1.         -0.22316588]
 [-0.22316588  1.        ]] 
which shows a small negative correlation.

We can then plot the x,y values:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline      # remove if not in Jupyter notebook
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This gives us the following plot - sting that there is no straight correlation between the month and monthly consumption.

[image: A put of x and y values]

This looks like it may be a cyclical consumption. Assuming that the 1-12 are months then it looks like consumption rises from the middle of the year to year end, then drops to the mid-year point, and rises again. Adding data from preceding to succeeding years would she if that was the case.

Comment: I think my example is not a good example because I put the months values as numerical values (1 till 12). But what if the month values are january, february, ... ? (if my qualitative variable can't be represented as numerical variable (like groupe-a, groupe-b, ...))

Comment: Ismael, in that case you could encode them as numeric values, as shown above. You can read more about it here: http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html This StackOverflow isn't a "how to" site. 



Please mark the question as answered by my response, above.